# Find roots of $x^4 + 4x^3 - 25x^2 - 16x + 84$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm not quite sure how to approach this, how are you supposed to quickly factor a 4th degree polynomial? For $x^4 + 4x^3 - 25x^2 - 16x + 84$ it's factored into $(x-3)(x-2)(x+2)(x+7)$ which like I said, I have no idea how to approach. Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Comment: Thanks, I thought rational root theorem only works for roots up to 3th degree polynomials  for some reason

Comment: @JakeDrone Works for polynomials of all degree.

Answer (score 1):

First, apply [Descartes' Rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs).  Now we know this polynomial has either two or zero positive real roots and either two or zero negative roots.  (How does this help?  If we happen to have a long list of candidate roots and, while checking through this list, we find two positive roots, we can immediately discard all remaining positive candidates.)

Then we apply the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  This tells us that the only rational candidate roots are a divisor of $84$ over a divisor of $1$:
$$  \{-84, -42, -26, -21, -14, -12, -7, -6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 14, 21, 26, 42, 84\}  \text{.}  $$
We see the coefficients $4$, $-25$, and $-16$, which are sums of products of roots.  These are "small", so we should probably start in the middle of the list and work our way out.

\begin{align*}
x&  &&|&  &x^4 + 4x^3 - 25x^2 - 16x + 84  \\ \hline
1&  &&|&  &1+4-25-16+84 > 0  \\
2&  &&|&  &16+32-100-32+84 = 0 &&\checkmark \\
3&  &&|&  &81 + 108 - 225 - 144 + 84 = 0  &&\checkmark
\end{align*}
Having found two real roots, any further real roots are negative.  Continuing the table, starting from $-1$, you will find $-2$ and then $-7$.

But we can go a little faster.  By [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) (or long division), once we have the root $x = 2$, we can reduce the polynomial.
$$  x^4 + 4x^3 - 25x^2 - 16x + 84 = (x-2)(x^3 + 6x^2 - 13x - 42)  $$
So any root of $x^3 + 6x^2 - 13x - 42$ is also a root of the original polynomial.  By the rule of signs, this has one positive real root and two or zero negative real roots.  Any rational root is a divisor of $42$ divided by a divisor of $1$.  This reduces the previous list of candidate roots to (excluding $1$, the one candidate we definitely verified is not a root)
$$  \{ -42, -21, -14, -7, -6, -3, -2, -1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42\}  \text{.}  $$
Testing $2$ in this reduced polynomial, we find $2$ is not a repeated root.  And then we find $3$ is a root:
$$  3^3 + 6\cdot 3^2 - 13\cdot 3 - 42 = 0  \text{.}  $$
That's the last possible positive root and we are left with
$$ \frac{x^3 + 6x^2 - 13x - 42}{x-3} = x^2 + 9x+14  \text{.}  $$

Of course, this is quadratic, so there is no reason to avoid directly applying the quadratic formula...  Alternatively, we compute the discriminant : $9^2 - 4 \cdot 14 = 25$, so the two roots differ by $\sqrt{25} = 5$.  (Since the discriminant is a square, we know the remaining two roots are rational, hence are on our list.)  Looking at the negatives on our list, the only pairs that differ by $5$ are $\{-1, -6\}$ and $\{-2, -7\}$.  Checking $-1$, we find that $-1$ is not a root, so $-2$ and $-7$ are the final two roots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synthetic division in $$p(x)=x^{4}+4x^{3}-25x^{2}-16x+84.$$

To do this, notice that the divisors of:

- $a=1$: $\{\pm1\}$.
- $b=84$: $\{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 4, \pm 6, \pm 7, \pm 12, \pm 14, \pm 28, \pm 42, \pm 84\}$.

Then the synthetic division gives us that $$p(x)=x^{4}+4x^{3}-25x^{2}-16x+84=(x-3)(x-2)(x+2)(x+7).$$

Comment: Did you need to check every single root to see if that works out?

Comment: The synthetic division method tells you what the possible roots might be. Do you know the method to do synthetic division?